# Why time.sleep() breaks syslog-ng in Python

Tags: python, logging, sleep, syslog

I have been trying to log a script output with [syslog-ng](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syslog-ng), however, if I use any time.sleep() function in my code, it breaks syslog-ng and stops logging the output of the script.

Here are the details.

```
// samplescript.py
import time

while True:
    print "hello world"
    time.sleep(5)
```

I use pipe to get it's output to syslog-ng, and I use unix [logger](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger) tool, so I'm calling the script like this;

```
$ python sampleoutput.py | logger
```

This is not generating any output to my log file. The code is simple, and working.

By the way, 
I don't thing anything wrong with syslog-ng conf file, since if i use the code below, it works as expected.

```
// samplescript.py    
while True:
    print "hello world"
```

**Q:** why time.sleep() is breaking syslog-ng? Is there any equivalence for sleep() function that I might use on my code?

thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to flush the buffered output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print

Comment: @GregorDorfbauer, Thanks man, I have never thought flushing the output, now it works, you saved me from a trouble :)

Comment: @GregorDorfbauer I think you have to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to flush the buffered stdout-stream:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

[How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)